# Does Android older version support Webrtc video chat in Android app

Tags: javascript, cordova, webrtc

I have developed a simple webrtc video chat  for web browser and it worked well in  in android firefox and chrome browser .  now i have started to create an android app using Cordova , but getusermedia api do not even get access to webcam. same code in Cordova browser platform ,do get access to webcam.

> currently testing on Android version 4.4 kitkat

. Permission is given for camera access as well. Am i missing something

> getusermedia API code

```
    const mediaStreamConstraints = {
    video: true,
  };

  // Video element where stream will be placed.
  const localVideo = document.querySelector('video');

  // Handles success by adding the MediaStream to the video element.
  function gotLocalMediaStream(mediaStream) {
    localVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
  }

  // Handles error by logging a message to the console with the error message.
  function handleLocalMediaStreamError(error) {
    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
  }

  // Initializes media stream.
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaStreamConstraints)
    .then(gotLocalMediaStream).catch(handleLocalMediaStreamError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android version 4.4 KitKat does not support WebRTC API.

In modern versions of Android the WebView component is based on the Chromium open source project which already includes WebRTC. More info on it is here https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview . As listed there all Android devices starting **from Android 5.0 support WebRTC API in WebView**.

Just in case you are seeking a ready-to-go Video Chat solution for Cordova - I recommend to try ConnectyCube Cordova video chat https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-videochat-cordova